# warning array comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c

So i have this problem where i have to input a string of unknown size with only lowercase letters then output the number of distinct letters.this is the main program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int test(char *T);
int main(){
    char T[100];int i=-1,j=0,nd=0;
    do{
            gets(T);

    }while((test(T))==1);
    do {
        i++;
        j=i;
        do{j++;

        }while ((T[i]!=T[j])||((T[j])!=""));
        if (T[j]=="")
        nd++; 
    }while (T[i+1]!="");
```

and this is my function test

```
int test(char *T){
    int i=-1,s;
    do {
        i++;

    }while (((islower(T[i])==1))||(T[i]==""));
    if ((T[i]=="")&&(i!=0))
s=0;
else s=1;
return s;   
}
```

the problem is that i get a lot of warnings "comparison between integer and pointer" everytime i compare a char of the array T and i don't knowhow to fix that.your help would be much appreciated.

Update:So i tried fixing the program following your advices and this is the new main program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int test(char *T);
int main(){
    char T[100];int i=-1,j=0,nd=0;
    do{
            gets(T);

    }while((test(T))==1);
    do {
        i++;
        j=i;
        do{j++;

        }while ((T[i]!=T[j])||((T[j])!='\0'));
        if (T[j]=='\0')
        nd++; 
    }while (T[i+1]!='\0');
printf("%d",nd);}
```

and this is function test

```
int test(char *T){
    int i=-1,s;
    do {
        i++;

    }while (((islower(T[i])==1))||(T[i]=='\0'));
    if ((T[i]=='\0')&&(i!=0))
s=0;
else s=1;
return s;   
}
```

I don't get anymore warnings and the program gets compiled with no problems but after i input the string in the execution nothing happens.

Comment: Are sure about OR (`||`) and not AND (`&&`)?

Comment: `T[i]==""` What is that meant to do? You need to use single quotes for a `char` but I'm not sure what char value you are trying to compare with.

Comment: In `if (T[i] == "")`, `""` is an array which converts to a pointer and `T[i]` is a char which converts to an integer. Compiler is warning you about the "apples vs oranges" comparison.

Comment: do you mean this ` }while (((islower(T[i])==1))||(T[i]==' '));
    if ((T[i]==' ')&&(i!=0)) `

Comment: @PaulOgilvie not sure program is not working properly tried both.

Comment: @kalyum i meant the value null and i tried single quote not working as well

Comment: @pmg  so how can i make the "" refer to value null or void

Comment: @AjithCNarayanan i get a warning on almost all the comparisons including that one

Comment: @Rami if you want to check for a NUL character, use `'\0'`, like in `if (T[i] == '\0')`. The *string* `"foo"` has 4 characters: `'f'`, `'o'`, `'o'`, and `'\0'`.

Comment: @pmg oh i see thanks.i'll try that out and see if it works

Comment: So guys i updated the problem if you could land me a hand again that would be awesome.Also thank you all for you helpful comments.Didn't really expect that since it's my first question on this platform hehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You function `test` should return 1 if the string contains only lowercase letters, and 0 otherwise. Unfortunately, it is not doing that.

You should first test if the character is a letter and then if it's a lowercase letter. Or more efficiently, you test if the character is in the range 'a' to 'z'.

Another problem of your code is the use of `do` `while` loops which makes the code difficult to understand and executes the loop once.

Here is a better implementation of the `test` function:

```c
int test(char *T){
    // reject empty strings
    if(T[0] == '\0')
        return 0;
    // reject strings containing non lowercase letter
    for(int i = 0; T[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if((T[i] < 'a') || (T[i] > 'z'))
            return 0;
    // string is not empty and contains only lowercase letters
    return 1;
```

---

Counting the different letters can be made more readable by using a `for` loop instead of a `go` `while` loop.

```c
int nd = 0;
for(int i = 0; T[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if(T[j] == T[i])
            break; // quit inner loop
        nd++;
    }
}
```

This code examine each letter and see if it has been seen before. It is thus different from yours.

A problem in your code is the test `(T[i]!=T[j])||((T[j])!='\0')`. It should be && instead of ||, and testing if the end of string is reached should be performed first. The test should be `(T[j]!='\0')&&(T[i]!=T[j])`.

Answer (score 0):

So my code is finally working here's the final main program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int test(char *T);
int main(){
    char T[100];int i,j,nd=0;
    do{
            gets(T);

    }while((test(T))==0);
for(i = 0; T[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    j=i;
    do{
        j++;
    }while ((T[j]!='\0')&&(T[j]!=T[i]));
    if (T[j]=='\0')
    nd++;
    }
```

(@chmike i used the code you posted with a little adjustment on the loop)
and for the function test i used the code that posted @chmike as well.
Huge thanks to all of you guys for the help you provided :)